# Click "Download csv" button using Selenium and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, selenium, csv, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to download the csv file from this website: https://invasions.si.edu/nbicdb/arrivals?state=AL&submit=Search+database&begin=2000-01-01&end=2020-11-11&type=General+Cargo&bwms=any

To do so, I need to click the CSV button, which downloads the CSV file. However, I need to do this for multiple links, which is why I want to use Selenium to automate the task of clicking on the link.

The code I have currently runs, but it does not actually download the csv file to the designated folder (or anywhere for that matter).

Here is the code I currently have:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("download.default_directory=folder") # Set the download Path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

url = 'https://invasions.si.edu/nbicdb/arrivals?state=AL&submit=Search+database&begin=2000-01-01&end=2020-11-11&type=General+Cargo&bwms=any'

driver.get(url)

python_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "csvbutton", " " ))]')
python_button.click()
```

I would appreciate any help with this! Thanks

Comment: Hi, do you help clicking the a tag with the words CSV? If so a simple xpath would be //a[text()='CSV'] or //a[@class='csvbutton'].

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem using this way:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# url of initial page with data
url = 'https://invasions.si.edu/nbicdb/arrivals?state=AL&submit=Search+database&begin=2000-01-01&end=2020-11-11&type=General+Cargo&bwms=any'
# name of csv file where to store downloaded csv data
csv_file_name = '/Users/eilyasov/Documents/arrivals_data.csv'

# get html content of initial page
html_data = requests.get(url=url) \
                    .content
# generate Beautifulsoup object based on hrml content of initial page
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup=html_data)
# extract url extension of downloadable csv file
csv_url_extension = soup.find(name='a', attrs={'class': 'csvbutton'}) \
                        .get(key='href')
# construct url of downloadable csv file
csv_url = 'https://invasions.si.edu' + csv_url_extension
# get content of downloadable csv file and saving it to file
response = requests.get(url=csv_url)
if response.status_code == 200:
    with open(csv_file_name, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(response.content)
```

Comment: @scrapingsarah, did this approach help you solve the problem?