# Python/Selenium - How to save CSV created by JavaScript directly to a variable

Tags: python, selenium, csv, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I currently use Selenium to click a download link to download a CSV file into directory, wait for the download to complete, then read the file from directory into a python variable.

I want to deploy the script into a Docker container and as far as i'm aware, I can't load the CSV the way I currently am.
I also don't know how the CSV file is created by the download button so I can't call `webdriver.Firefox.execute_script()`.

---

Is there a way to intercept Firefox when downloading to see the file and save it straight to a variable at that point?

Is there an easy way to see how the CSV is created? (as I can't read the website code)

If no to the above, is there a way I can perform my current actions inside a Docker container that will be hosted on a cloud server?

**My current code for reference**

```
# Driver set-up
firefox_driver_path = "Path to geckodriver.exe"
downloaded_csv_path = "Path to specific .csv file when downloaded"
firefox_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
firefox_options.headless = True
firefox_options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "Path to download .csv file")
firefox_options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
firefox_options.set_preference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", True)
firefox_options.set_preference("browser.download.viewableInternally.enabledTypes", "")
firefox_options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf;text/plain;application/text;text/xml;text/csv;application/xml")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=firefox_driver_path, options=firefox_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Navigate to webpage, perform actions 
driver.get("website URL")
# Perform other actions to navigate to the download button
driver.find_element_by_id('DownloadButton').click()

# Check if download is complete
time_to_wait = 10
time_counter = 0
while not os.path.exists(downloaded_csv_path):
    time.sleep(1)
    time_counter += 1
    if time_counter > time_to_wait:
        sys.exit("First CSV download didn't complete")

# Read the CSV data and delete the downloaded file
with open(downloaded_csv_path) as csvFile:
  my_CSV = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=',')
os.unlink(downloaded_csv_path)
```

**UPDATE**

One download button has what seems an Angular function attached to it `ng-click="$ctrl.onExportTransactions()"`.
I know nothing of angular and after searching every source file for the website (including 3 that are named "Angular xxx", I can't find function called "onExportTransactions". Is there a way this function can be invoked from Python/Selenium?

Comment: do you have the link to the page? You might be able to `GET` request the file

Comment: It's actually within my online bank accounts... so yeah I have the page link, but I can't share it as it requires being logged in. I will do some searches and try to find if and how i can GET request it.

Comment: I found this answer... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65040545/click-download-csv-button-using-selenium-and-beautiful-soup
But when inspecting the download button, I see no href attribute so i'm not sure how that will work.

Comment: Hi, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: "[@ng-click='$ctrl.onExportTransactions()']" as an xpath might work while using click or using driver.execture to invoke the method directly.

Comment: Neither option works. "not a legal xpath" for the .click(), and a "key error" when using that path in the execute command.
I feel like my last option is going to be manually scraping each line of data and create my own CSV. Just thought downloading it would be easier.